# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult

Tags: java, exception, hadoop

I have created a web service in netbeans 6.7 and one project for client. The web service has a method which does some query from database and returns me an array.
Calling the web service method in client.jsp file in web clients service gives error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:273)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:354)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:398)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:425)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
`
```

I have imported jars from hadoop.

Answer (score 6):

I met the same exception with you. In my cases, it's caused by the jetty library conflicts with Hadoop/HBase libraries( maybe both contain org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult method). I solve this bug by adding following exclusions into Hadoop/HBase dependencies:

```
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version2}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api-2.1</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jinferng. I had the same problem and solved it by removing anything referencing
-  `org.mortbay.jetty`
-  `javax.servlet` (old 2.x verions)
- `javax.servlet.jsp`
- `tomcat`
inside 
`<groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>`
`<artifactId>hbase-rest</artifactId>`
`<version>1.6.0</version>`
You can view all dependencies by issueing `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 4):

try running by removing ecj-x.x.x.jar from your tomcat library

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple versions of the library containing `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult` on your classpath, and they are ordered so that a version in which the method `CompilationResult.getProblems()` does not exist (or was incompatibly changed) comes first on the classpath, probably because it is provided by whatever container you're running in.

Possible solutions:

- Reorder the classpath to avoid the problem
- If it is a Maven project, exclude the duplicate JARs as dependencies (in NetBeans, expand the *Libraries* node and right click the library and choose *Exclude Dependency* from the popup menu)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with jars from hadoop that in turn depend on some jetty packages. I solved it by placing the following exclusions in the offending dependency:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 1):

I excluded the following dependencies from "org.apache.hbase" in the pom.xml file

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
 <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
<exclusion>
     <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
     <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
     <artifactId>servlet-api-2.1</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of conflict of dependency jar but its tough to find out which jar is the cause of conflict.

So to check conflict, in **pom.xml** there is `Dependency Hierarchy` tab in eclipse. In `Resolved Dependency` section check whether there are two jars with same name. If found then exclude one of them from parent dependency.

[image]

In my case it was jsp-api jar, By clicking on jsp-api jar I found that parent dependency is **activemq-core** so I excluded jsp-api jar from activemq-core dependency and its working fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the similar problem and all these answers were not solving my problem. I was using drools in spark and implemented my code using java. I got the same error on cluster (On local system in eclipse it was working fine), the cause for this problem was ecj-x.x.x.jar file. On cluster some other version of jar file was present which was creating the compilation problem for drool file (.drl file). So in driver classpath I externally added the current version of ecj jar file and it worked for me.

Command which I used during spark-submit:

```
spark2-submit --driver-class-path ecj-4.4.2.jar --class Yourclass Yourbundeledjarfile.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I started working on hadoop and wanted to integrate to be put in hadoop from app. SO added hadoop maven dependency and all these errors thrown by app. 
Once I removed my hadoop dependency then errors  gone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the correct Servlet API version: Tomcat 7.x expects version 3.0.x, not the 3.1.x I'd tried using. See also '[What does offending class tell me on server startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096837/what-does-offending-class-tell-me-on-server-startup/31342449)'

Answer (score 0):

HI this is because of jsp page compilers, In my case the jsp pages is developed in older version of tomcat then i deployed into new version of tomcat then i got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;  then i added the 'jasper-*.*'  and 'ecj.*,el-*.*'jars to the build path. I succeeded.

Comment: Actually project is developed by some one in his environment now the task  came to me i dont know what versions of jars he used, then i took the code into eclipse then i got the same error, in that error msg we r able to c the some jasper compiler issues, then i added the following jar to the build path of project in eclipse those r  ecj-4.4.2.jar,el-api.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar. then the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case appears I had "jdtcore" dependency being pulled in by one thing (jasperreports), and ecj dependency being pulled in by another (drools).  Conflict, as mentioned by Tim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605323/32453)!

Fix was figure out which two dependencies were pulling it in, then either update jasperreports, so it no longer had the jdtcore dependency, or exclude jdtcore dependency from the jasperreports' dependency in the pom file.  Here's the exclude:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <version>4.5.1</version>
  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <!-- conflict with newer drools knowledge-api's ecj  -->
      <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Seems to fix:

Attempt to fix sdb dying at startup, with our new drools'ish jar:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
        at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$3.acceptResult(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:411)
```