# What does offending class tell me on server startup?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm having the jee7 web api as dependency. I can start my app on `tomcat` application successfully, but what does the following "offending class" statements tell me? Do I have to take any actions?

```
Jan 13, 2014 5:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Information: validateJarFile(C:\Users\me\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\wtpwebapps\app\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jan 13, 2014 5:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Information: validateJarFile(C:\Users\me\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\wtpwebapps\app\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you're using tomcat 7, you should use javaee-web-api 6.0. JEE 7 will be supported in upcoming Tomcat 8

Comment: I also tried 6.0 as well as javax.servlet-api 3.1.0. same result on both

Comment: Have you considered looking up section 10.7.2 of the Servlet Specification 3.0?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems like you (your Servlet container) are trying to load some classes that have already been loaded. The `servlet-api` and `el-api` should be provided by the Servlet container.

Change your pom.xml to account for that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @membersound If you re-built it correctly, this path `WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` shouldn't exist.

Comment: I had the same problem when using IntelliJ builds instead of Maven.  The   `<scope>provided</scope>` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue during a project using Eclipse.

Doing below things resolved the issue

1. Added javax.*****.jar to the build path
2. Removed the project - gave clean build and add the project and finally published....!!

Bingo...!!

This resolved my issue. Hope this helps.

Thanks,

mskr.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem for developers who are using Maven as a build tool. when , we include the servlet-api as a project dependency i.e pom.xml like this :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>  javax.servlet</groupId>

<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
```

add scope as provided in the above dependency as following .

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the correct Servlet API version: Tomcat 7.x expects version 3.0.x, not the 3.1.x I'd tried using.