# /WEB-INF/lib/javaee-web-api-7.0.jar - jar not loaded

Tags: java, tomcat7

I uploaded WAR on server. I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096837/what-does-offending-class-tell-me-on-server-startup) and based on that I added the required jar but it is showing following error.

```
Feb 13, 2015 10:29:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/work/Catalina/myproject.com/MyProject/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 13, 2015 10:29:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/work/Catalina/myproject.com/MyProject/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

I can run the application on my localhost, testfile of both localhost and server are

```
Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Servlet Specification Version : 3.0 
JSP version : 2.2
```

Java version on server is

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.0.el6_6-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Java version on local machine is

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to add the `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` to you web application's `/WEB-INF/lib/` directory because they are already provided by the application server. Adding it would only cause class loading conflict and hence the deployment would fail.

The question you've linked states that although you declare it as a dependency in your Maven's build xml file, you mark its `<scope>` to *provided* i.e. the jar would be provided by the container and hence should not be bundled inside the generated *war* artifact.