# ClassNotFoundException from Maven Dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am working on a Maven project in Eclipse.

I added a maven dependency to my project like below (this dependency is located in my local maven repository):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>j2ee</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

In the package explorer, I can see that the correct classes are added, and I don't get any errors when referencing the classes in my code.

However, when I try to add the project to my Tomcat 7 server running on localhost, I get the following error on server startup:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.cci.ConnectionSpec
```

When I look in `wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib` I can see that the JAR file containing the above class is there, so I don't understand why I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` on this class.

Comment: are you sure that server run time library is included in you probjec build path ?

Comment: Check the Tomcat logs (I think it should be in catalina.log) to be sure there is no [offending class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21096837/3127111) around.

Comment: Server run time library is included in the java build path, and I'm not seeing anything in the Tomcat logs

Comment: Any Updates of the problem?
 I have currently the exact same Issue.
A MulitModule Maven-Projekt where I get ClassNotFound Exceptions while Runtime.